# Creat a macro to cut and paste rows of data that have a date data entry in a column

Tags: excel, paste, vba

Firstly I must apologies for what must be a question that's been asked in numerous guises.

I have a ToDo list to help manage my priorities & I simply want to search the Completed column on the ToDo list sheet and for any date data entries found, then cut, delete & paste the entire row onto the Archive sheet, stacking rows in the next available unpopulated row.

I did have a functioning macro, but sadly the worksheet became corrupted and being a complete VBA novice has made this task rather daunting.

Thank you in advance for any time spared.

**ToDo List Example Screen Dump [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8J3Ap.png)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub go_through_rows ()
lastrow = Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
for i to lastrow
If Not IsEmpty(CELLS(i, & "G").Value)
rows(i & ":" & i).select
selection.cut
SHEETS("target sheet name").activate
CELLS("A1").select
SELECTION.End(XlDOWN).select 'jumps to the last value in the sheet make sure there is data here already
ActiveCell.OFFSET(1, 0).select
Paste
Sheets("sheet with the raw data").activate
END IF
next i
```

Comment: Sadly this doesn't appear to work and stops at;

Sub go_through_rows ()
lastrow = Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
for i to lastrow

Answer (score 0):

Resolved with the following;

```
Sub CopyRows()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Sheets("ToDo List").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
Sheets("ToDo List").Range("$A$1:$H$" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="<>"
Sheets("ToDo List").Range("$A$2:$H$" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy Sheets("Archive").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
Sheets("ToDo List").Range("$A$2:$H$" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
If Sheets("ToDo List").FilterMode Then Sheets("ToDo List").ShowAllData
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub